# .Net, Send key press/message to command line process running without window?

Tags: .net, command-line, process, keypress

Basically I'm attempting to create a simple GUI to use with Robocopy. I'm opening Robocopy with a process and redirecting the output to a textbox as follows:

```
    With MyProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = "c:\windows\system32\robocopy.exe"
        .Arguments = Chr(34) & srce & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & dest & Chr(34)"
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = False
    End With
    MyProcess.Start()
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

You can pause a Robocopy process by using the pause/break key. I'm looking to replicate that capability with a pause button on the form, but I'm having a hell of a time trying to find any code to adapt that sends a key press successfully. I guess it comes down to not knowing how to send info to the "invisible" Robocopy process. Thanks in advance. Let me know if there's any additional info I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give PostMessage a try. I believe that even if the window is hidden, you can get the window handle.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Then:

```
PostMessage(MyProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0x100, 0x13, 0);
PostMessage(MyProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0x101, 0x13, 0);
```

`0x100` means key down, `0x101` means key up and `0x13` is Pause. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx for virtual key codes.

Comment: Yeah. That direct piece of code isn't working either. But I suspect it's probably somewhere along the right track, and something I've tried a bit. It might be a problem with how I'm setting up my process or something. Who knows?! Either way, as close to an answer as I suspect I'll get. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [PSSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897540%28en-us%29.aspx) to suspend the process without having to send keystrokes - you can [get the processId to pass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from your MyProcess object.

Comment: That would be a likely candidate. I'm looking to use this on multiple machines though, and I'd rather avoid the hassle of having to install extra software. It looks like you'd need to install pstools, correct?

Comment: You'd have have the .exe file available locally, yes, but I'm not sure it would have to be _installed_ as such..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are redirecting StdIn and StdOut I'll assume Robocopy.exe is a `console` application.

If that's the case then pressing <kbd>Pause</kbd> is actually pausing the console that is hosting robocopy.

I don't really know the actual answer to your question but this might get you on the right track.  Maybe the `SendKeys` function will help.

Comment: Yeah. That's pretty much where I'm at. Just can't figure out how to use sendkeys (or whatever) properly.

Comment: Something else to try might be the SendMessage Win32 function with the WM_KEYDOWN message.